# rank dates with duplicates in R

Tags: r

Starting from this dataframe

```
DF <- data.frame(class= c('a','b','c','d','e','f'), 
                 date = c('2018-01-09', '2018-01-09', '2018-01-06', '2018-01-06', '2018-01-07', '2018-01-07'))
DF$date  <-as.Date(DF$date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
```

I would like to rank the column date to produce this result

```
DF <- data.frame(class= c('a','b','c','d','e','f'), 
                 date = c('2018-01-09', '2018-01-09', '2018-01-06', '2018-01-06', '2018-01-07', '2018-01-07'),
                 rank = c(3,3,1,1,2,2))
DF$date  <-as.Date(DF$date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
```

I tried this

```
DF <- DF %>% mutate(rank = rank(date)) %>% arrange(date)
```

but it gives me

```
DF <- data.frame(class= c('c','d','e','f','a','b'), 
                 date = c('2018-01-06', '2018-01-06', '2018-01-07', '2018-01-07', '2018-01-09', '2018-01-09'),
                 rank = c(1.5,1.5,3.5,3.5,5.5,5.5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dense_rank`

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
     mutate(rank = dense_rank(date))
#  class       date rank
#1     a 2018-01-09    3
#2     b 2018-01-09    3
#3     c 2018-01-06    1
#4     d 2018-01-06    1
#5     e 2018-01-07    2
#6     f 2018-01-07    2
```

Comment: Sorry Akrun, Thank you again!